# Next Global css issue

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, next.js

ON my old computer It is running perfectly but on other computer it is giving this error as style already imported in _app.js . I am using nvm and checked with all versions .

error - ./styles/index.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom . Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages_app.js

[image]
[image]
I want to run this app smoothly on my computer. I did npm cache clean --force , I have deleted nodemodules, packgLock and installed. but not working.

Comment: Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: Yes , uploaded Please check @RobinThomas

Comment: Can you check if you have imported `styles/index.css` anywhere else in your app besides `pages/_app.js`?

Comment: no it is already running fine on other computer

Comment: show us the style file

Comment: Can you also delete your `.next` directory and rebuild?